# Edit value in table via button click (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, button, controller, icons

I'm a little ashamed, because for over 2 hours now I can't figure out how to do this. But I'm rather new to Rails, so bear with me :)

I have two groups of users: Posters and Doers
Then there is a model "Assignments". Assignments are created by Posters (have a belong_to relationship with them).
Doers can then select assignments from a pool of unassigned ones and assign them to themselves (that's why Assignments also have a belong_to relation with Doers).

On the page itself I have this code at the moment (changed it like 20 times over the last hour):

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Assign to me</th>
    </tr>
  </thhead>      
  <tbody>
    <% @assignments.each do |assignment| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= assignment.title %></td>
        <td>
           <%= link_to(edit_assignment_path(assignment), :doer => current_doer.id, confirm: 'Really take this assignment on?') do%>
             <i class="icon-folder-open", alt="assign"></i>
           <% end %> 
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

With this code in the AssignmentController:

```
def edit
  @assignment = Assignment.find(params[:id])
  @doer = Doer.find(params[:doer])
  if @patient.assign(@doer)
    redirect_to dashboard_index_path, notice: 'Successfully assigned to you'
  else
    redirect_to dashboard_index_path, alert: 'Error while trying to assign to you'
  end
end
```

And this in Assignment.rb :

```
def assign(current_doer)
  if self.doer_id != nil then 
    false 
  else 
    self.doer_id << current_doer
    true
  end
end
```

As you can see I'm logged in as a Doer in this example. And I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this correct and clean!

I also tried variations of the link_to code part, the assign function and so on.
At the moment I get the error, that  @doer = Doer.find(params[:doer]) cannot search for an id of Nil. I know that this means that I don't really send the doer_id parameter along correctly, but I'm at my beginners-knowledge end.

Thank you very much for helping me out here.

Greetings,
Lordylike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost have it right, when using a link_to with a block, the way it accepts parameters changes a little bit. Pass your parameters along using the path helper like this.

```
<%= link_to(edit_assignment_path(assignment, doer: current_doer.id), confirm: 'Really take this assignment on?') do %>
  <i class="icon-folder-open", alt="assign"></i>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Works like a charm :)
Thank you very much (although, I think you missed a closing bracket in your code ;) ).
Do you know if there's a way to make this more "secure"? I'm currently using devise and I would like Doers only to be able to accept an Assignment when it's shown in the pool. Currently I can just edit my address and accept Assignments of any stage and for Doers that are not me. :)

Comment: For checking the user, just compare the `params[:doer]` value with `current_doer` in your controller, that should prevent you from assigning to different users other than yourself.  As far as the pool, I'm not sure what your using to track state changes, but if you are tracking when an assignment is considered ready to be accepted, like is a database, then you could also use that in your controller, just check the assignment for whatever you consider to be a ready state before assigning someone to it. Hope this helps.